# WebGL shader working differently on mobile

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, babylonjs

I'm implementing a [reaction-diffusion](https://www.karlsims.com/rd.html) algorithm in shader. In every iteration I render the result into a texture and for the next iteration I use it as an input (`uniform sampler2D grid;`) for the next calculation. I use float texture for the render target.

It is working on desktop as expected but on mobile (Xiaomi Redmi 4, GPU: Adreno 505) it generates different patterns. I use the same resolution for the textures.

I've tried changing `precision highp` to `mediump` and `lowp`. On desktop it is working correctly with all precisions. On mobile `mediump` and `lowp` gives a new result compared to `highp` but it is still wrong.

**Edit:**

When creating `BABYLON.RenderTargetTexture` I use `BABYLON.Engine.TEXTURETYPE_FLOAT`. If I change it to `BABYLON.Engine.TEXTURETYPE_HALF_FLOAT` then it also produces a bad result on desktop. So the issue is probably still caused by float precision.

```
precision highp float;

varying vec2 vUV;
uniform sampler2D grid;
uniform vec2 step; // 1 / (textureSize - 1)
uniform float dt; // 1.0

float da = 1.0;
float db = 0.5;
float f = 0.0545;
float k = 0.062;

vec2 lapl(vec2 uv) {
  vec2 res = 
    // Top row
    0.05 * texture2D(grid, uv + vec2(-step.x, step.y)).rg +
    0.2 * texture2D(grid, uv + vec2(0., step.y)).rg +
    0.05 * texture2D(grid, uv + vec2(step.x, step.y)).rg +
    // Middle row
    0.2 * texture2D(grid, uv + vec2(-step.x, 0.)).rg +
    -1. * texture2D(grid, uv + vec2(0., 0.)).rg +
    0.2 * texture2D(grid, uv + vec2(step.x, 0.)).rg +
    // Bottom row
    0.05 * texture2D(grid, uv + vec2(-step.x, -step.y)).rg +
    0.2 * texture2D(grid, uv + vec2(0., -step.y)).rg +
    0.05 * texture2D(grid, uv + vec2(step.x, -step.y)).rg;

  return res;
}

void main(void) {
  vec2 c = texture2D(grid, vUV).rg;
  vec2 la = lapl(vUV);
  float rgg = c.r * c.g * c.g;
  float a = c.r + (da * la.r - rgg + f * (1. - c.r)) * dt;
  float b = c.g + (db * la.g + rgg - (k + f) * c.g) * dt;

  gl_FragColor = vec4(a, b, 0., 1.);
}
```

Comment: Even if it's a 32-bit texture and you use `highp` everywhere, the standard gives considerable leniency with regards to how much precision you get. It might be the case for example that you have 32-bit float on your PC and 24-bit float on your phone

Comment: Thanks @Andrea . Is there a way to check the precision? I've tried ```gl.getShaderPrecisionFormat(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, gl.HIGH_FLOAT)``` and I get ```{ rangeMin: 127, rangeMax: 127, precision: 23 }``` on both desktop and mobile.

Comment: Try [this test](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/misc/shader-precision-format.html?webglVersion=1&quiet=0&quick=1)

Comment: @gman Thank you, I ran it. On mobile lowp and mediump are 10, highp is 23. On desktop all of them are 23. I'm using highp so it should be the same. But it's very weird because I continued working on the project and now all of a sudden it is working correctly on mobile too. I haven't changed anything for the simulation, I just also return now approximated normal map values on the blue and alpha channels. Alpha blending is disabled. I have really no idea why it is working all of a sudden.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it's working, shame it's not clear what fixed it though.